# How do I update the size of a Google Document file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I make a copy of the file (the original file is 80 MB in size). I delete more than half of the content from it via Apps Script. And as a result, the edited copy also weighs 80 MB. How to fix it?

Even if I make a copy of a document where content is already removed, the size of the copied file is still 80 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wait up to 24hrs to see the file size / storage quota consumed updated .

This is because Google Drive storage is "in the cloud" meaning that the file is not assigned to a single storage unit.

One way to verify that the file size /  storage quota consumed will be reduced is to export the file using a downloadable format like PDF, DOCX, etc., before and after the changes be realized. Then compare the *before* vs *after* files.

Note: Google documents and spreadsheets have a version history. Contrary as happens with downloable files like PDF that old versions can be deleted, old versions of Google documenst and spreadsheets can't be deleted.

Resources

- [How your Google storage works](https://support.google.com/googleone/answer/9312312?hl=en)

Comment: When exporting a file, the size is specified correctly (in my case it is 30 MB instead of 80 MB) regardless of the time that has passed since the last change. 

But even in this case, the size of exactly Google Document is 80 MB. This value is displayed in the Disk interface and through the .getSize() method. 

For documents that were created a long time ago and more than 24 hours have passed, the values do not change either. For all, 80 MB of the original template is indicated as the value.